# Import Activity First line is Skipped

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio, import

I'm using an import activity to import one file from FTP, this file does not have header, the first line starts with data that I would like to import into a Data Extension (action: overwrite).

But I've noticed that every time the first line is missing. It is like the Import Activity requires a headers.

Is there one way to import all rows from a file without column header?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your file does not contain column headers, I expect that you map the columns by ordinal in your import activity - since you only have the order of the columns you can reference (see an example in the image below):

[image]

You must ensure, that the checkbox saying *Import file has column headers* in unchecked, as it will otherwise skip row 1, incorrectly assuming it is a header.